# Running dosbox from command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file

I'd like to run `dosbox` with params from batch file like so

```
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe -noconsole -exit"
```

but get an error:

```
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe -noconsole -exit"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to run dosbox with params?

Comment: So run dosbox with params as `@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe" -noconsole -exit`

Comment: Sorry but i've tried this already and it doesn't work - dosbox runs without taking the prams into account - pops-up the window...

Comment: This is from my shortcut `"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74\DOSBox.exe" -userconf -noconsole -fullscreen`. This is what help (its in the DOSBox folder) says about `-exit` _*-exit*
        DOSBox will close itself when the DOS application "name" ends._ You are missing `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Run it like this
`@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe" -noconsole -exit`

The double quotes have to bracket the excuted file and its path, but must not include the parameters.

Comment: Sorry but i've tried this already and it doesn't work - dosbox runs without taking the prams into account - pops-up the window...

Comment: Please change to the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3 and test the command from there:
DOSBox.exe -noconsole -exit
Do you see any difference? Does it now take the parameter into account? If not, the parameters don't do what you like them to do, that is, in that case, check the parameters. I'm not familiar with DosBox, but according to the usage you should provide a 'name' paramter?

Comment: The `-noconsole` options refers to the startup console normally displayed in addition to the main DOSBox window.